# How to find out json response is an empty JSON object in android?

Tags: java, android, json, rest

I'm facing the problem that I get an empty JSON Object from the server.

How can I find out that JSON response from the server is an **empty JSON Object** `{}` or **others**?
I set `jObject!=null`  condition for it but it doesn't work.

**Here is my code:**

```java
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);

if (jObject!=null) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.successfull_unsubscribe, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ShareData.saveData(getApplicationContext(), "simType", "null");
    ShareData.saveData(getApplicationContext(), "firstLaunch", "true");

    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity2.this, WelcomeActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

Comment: which json library are you using ?

Comment: I use volley library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try length check or toString.

eg: `jObject.length() == 0`

eg: `jObject.toString().equals("{}")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jObject.keys().hasNext()` or `jObject.length() != 0`:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
if (jObject != null && jObject.length() != 0) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.successfull_unsubscribe, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ShareData.saveData(getApplicationContext(), "simType", "null");
    ShareData.saveData(getApplicationContext(), "firstLaunch", "true");

    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity2.this, WelcomeActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```